# JUnit testing for assertEqual NullPointerException

Tags: java, junit, junit4

I am not sure why the test case doesn't have an output of `true`. Both cases should give a `NullPointerException`.

I've tried doing this (Not exactly the same but it gives and output of `true`) :

```
    String nullStr = null;

//@Test
public int NullOutput1() {
    nullStr.indexOf(3);
    return 0;
}

//@Test(expected=NullPointerException.class)
public int NullOutput2() {
    nullStr.indexOf(2);
    return 0;
}

@Test(expected=NullPointerException.class)
public void testboth() {
    assertEquals(NullOutput1(), NullOutput2());
}
```

Runner:

```
import org.junit.runner.JUnitCore;
import org.junit.runner.Result;
import org.junit.runner.notification.Failure;

public class TestRunnerStringMethods {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Result result = JUnitCore.runClasses(TestJunitMyIndexOf.class);
        for (Failure failure : result.getFailures()) {
            System.out.println(failure.toString());
        }
        System.out.println(result.wasSuccessful());
    }
}
```

Method:

```
public static int myIndexOf(char[] str, int ch, int index) {
        if (str == null) {
            throw new NullPointerException();
        }
        // increase efficiency
        if (str.length <= index || index < 0) {
            return -1;
        }
        for (int i = index; i < str.length; i++) {
            if (index == str[i]) {
                return i;
            }
        }
        // if not found
        return -1;
    }
```

Test Case:

```
@Test(expected=NullPointerException.class)
public void testNullInput() {
    assertEquals(nullString.indexOf(3), StringMethods.myIndexOf(null, 'd',3));
}
```

Comment: It's entirely unclear what you're trying to test or assert here. Why do you have both an assert and an expected exception in the same test method? The assert will never be reached due to the `NullPointerException`.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I believe you want to use `fail` here:

```
@Test(expected=NullPointerException.class)
public void testNullInput() {
    fail(nullString.indexOf(3));
}
```

Make sure to add `import static org.junit.Assert.fail;` if you need to.

Answer (score 13):

In Java 8 and JUnit 5 (Jupiter) we can assert for exceptions as follows.
Using `org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertThrows`

> **public static < T extends Throwable > T assertThrows(Class< T > expectedType,
>                                                      Executable executable)**
>
> Asserts that execution of the supplied executable throws an exception of the expectedType and returns the exception.
>
> If no exception is thrown, or if an exception of a different type is thrown, this method will fail.
>
> If you do not want to perform additional checks on the exception instance, simply ignore the return value.

```
@Test
public void itShouldThrowNullPointerExceptionWhenBlahBlah() {
    assertThrows(NullPointerException.class,
            ()->{
            //do whatever you want to do here
            //ex : objectName.thisMethodShoulThrowNullPointerExceptionForNullParameter(null);
            });
}
```

That approach will use the Functional Interface `Executable` in `org.junit.jupiter.api`.

Refer :

- http://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#writing-tests-assertions
- http://junit.org/junit5/docs/5.0.0-M2/api/org/junit/jupiter/api/Executable.html
- http://junit.org/junit5/docs/5.0.0-M4/api/org/junit/jupiter/api/Assertions.html#assertThrows-java.lang.Class-org.junit.jupiter.api.function.Executable-